# Post to azure function - Error parsing boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, json, ajax, azure

On my site I make a post request using a ajax call to an azure function url like so:

```
var name = $("input#name").val();
var number = $(input#number").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "azurefunctionurl.com",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        number: number,
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
        ...stuff here....
    },
    error: function () {
        ...stuff here...
    },
});
```

However in the error logs I see a message that says

> One or more errors occurred. ---> Error parsing boolean value. Path '', line 1, position 1.

My azure function code looks like

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Verbose($"Webhook was triggered!");

    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

    string name = data.name;
    string number = data.number;

    log.Verbose(name);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when you post by ajax with default content type, the form data will be

```
name=xxxx&number=yyyy
```

so whether you need to change your azure function codes to recognize the name value pair, or you need to set ajax post content type to

```
application/json
```